# What does the degree of freedom (df) mean in the results of log-likelihood `logLik`

Tags: r, likelihood, degrees-of-freedom

After doing the regression using `lm` for fixed effect model or `lmer` for mixed effects model, I pass the results to the `logLik`. Besides the value of log-likelihood, the function always returns a `df`, i.e. the degree of freedom.

However, the degree of freedom does not equal to the number of parameters in the model, `df` always larger. So what does the `df` mean exactly?

The reason I care about the `df` is that later I will use the `BIC` (Bayesian Information Criterion) to do the model selection. The BIC is defined as
`BIC=-2*logLik+k*log(n)` where `k` is the number of parameters and `n` is the number of observations. When I pass my `logLik` value to the expression of `BIC`, the result is exactly the same when I use the build in `BIC` function in `R` if I specify the number of parameters as the `df` in `logLik`. Which means, in the build in `BIC` function, they also use the `df` as `k` when they calculate `BIC`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to understand degrees of freedom?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16921/how-to-understand-degrees-of-freedom)

Comment: Usually it is something like sample size minus number of parameters estimated. It can be a little more complicated though. Read the suggested question yours is a duplicate of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The help file for the logLik() function mentions that it returns the number of (estimated) parameters in the model as the degrees of freedom (df).

If you fit a linear model like the one below:

```
m <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars) 

summary(m) 

logLik(m)
```

you will see that the model includes an intercept parameter, a slope parameter quantifying the effect of the predictor hp on mpg and an error variance (or standard deviation) parameter. These add up to three parameters, which is exactly what logLik() returns for the model.

If you fit a linear mixed effects model like this:

```
require(nlme) 

M <- lme(distance ~ age + Sex, data = Orthodont, random = ~ 1)

summary(M) 

logLik(M)
```

then you'll see that the model includes the following parameters: a fixed effect intercept, a fixed effect of age, a fixed effect of Sex, a parameter denoting the standard deviation of the random intercept and a standard deviation of the within-subject model errors. That makes for five parameters, which is what the logLik() returns.